# Microphone not working Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, microphone

Since installing Xubuntu 14.04 the microphone has not worked either on my Laptop or Desktop installations. This is a system wide issue not confined to SKYPE.

Testing I have performed thus far:

- Volume control

  Not muted.
- Volume control > Recording

  While on Skype test call, the mic level does not move and there is no input devices showing.
- Skype

  Unselected 'Allow Skype to automatically adjust mixer levels'.
- `~$ arecord -d 10 /tmp/test-mic.wav`

  Plays back interference noise only.
- `~$ sudo aplay -l`

  `**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
  card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: CX20585 Analog [CX20585 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`
- Volume Levels

  Unable to locate 'System->Preferences->Sound' in Settings, does not seem to exist?
- Alsamixer settings

  I Do not see 'Mic' tab only 'Mic Boost' tab? I tried increaing the 'Internal Mic Boost' level and disabling 'Auto-Mute Mode' but no change.

  [image]

Edit:

**Add additional drivers**

- Installed latest driver for my Nvidia graphics card
- Confirmed that drivers are in use 
  `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`
  `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`
- Checked hardware acceleration
  `Quadro FX 1700/PCIe/SSE2`

**Further Alsamixer testing**

- aplay -lL

`default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1988 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1988 Analog [AD1988 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: AD1988 Digital [AD1988 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1988 Alt Analog [AD1988 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

- F6: Select sound card: nvidia/nvidia-340

`Error Cannot Can not open mixer device 'nvidia'. No such file or directory`

**LSPCI**

- lspci -nn | grep -i audio

`00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:3a3e]`

- `lspci`

`03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84GL [Quadro FX 1700] (rev a1)`

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In alsamixer, press F4 to get to the mic settings,  and disable this "Auto-mute" thing I see on screenshot too.
And the main thing is - use `pavucontrol` instead of alsamixer and stop reading that 10-year-old manual you have found all this things in. Pulseaudio overrides and essentially deprecates all this stuff.